# mat-form-field input has same background as page defined with CSS

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I have the following code:

**Html:**

```
<form fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
 [formGroup]="deleteForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()">
    <mat-form-field color="accent"  appearance="outline">
      <input
        type="password"
        matInput
        required
        placeholder="Re-enter your password"
        formControlName="password">
      <mat-error>Please re-enter your password.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field></button>
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading$ | async"></mat-spinner>
<button *ngIf="!(isLoading$ | async)" type="submit" mat-flat-button
 color="accent" [disabled]="deleteForm.invalid">Remove</button>

  </form>
```

**ts file:**

```
this.deleteForm = new FormGroup({
      password: new FormControl('', {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      })
    });
```

For some reason my mat-form-field has the same background color has my background css for the page. 
E.g. My background was white.. so my forms was not visible because the mat-form-fields were also white. 
Now I went with a darker color as a background so my fields are visible, but only the text is now visible (that's still white). Image added of the result.

[image]

I have no clue what the issues might be.

Comment: i think that how the components are made, they should have background according to parent. So, if you want specific mat-form-field to have different style you can always override the properties or provide your specific styles to the component field.

Comment: I find it strange that the text color is white by default. I expected that if the background was white.. the text color atleast went to black of some other darker color ;s

Comment: yes you are right, i missed that then we have to check your code as i have tested with material components and all have black text color.

Comment: I'm running the latest material repo (7.0.2). I don't seem to have any other code that influences the mat-form-field fields.

Comment: Okay, can you please create a demo over stackBlitz, so that we can close the issue there, See for reference : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zghdx8?file=src%2Fstyles.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason my mat-form-field has the same background color has my
>   background css for the page.

This is normal. Form fields do not have any background - they are transparent. Whatever is 'behind' the form fields will determine the background.

> I have no clue what the issues might be.

You are trying to style various aspects of your app and the Angular Material components using your own CSS but without using theming. If you have themed your app properly, all colors including foreground and background will work properly together. If you try to bypass theming by applying your own background colors to pages for example, you may encounter conflicts and run into problems like the one you are having.

It *sounds* like you want a 'dark' theme - light text on a dark background. You can do that by applying a dark theme - either a predefined one or a custom one. For more information, refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming.

There are plenty of posts here on how to customize theming including changing foreground and background colors.